# How can Ioccurrences of a pattern in a string and print their starting positions:?

Tags: python

Sample Input String: "ATATAGTAGATGAATGGGATAGAAAG"
Sample Input Pattern: "TAG"
Sample Output: 4    7    20

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use the `re` module for this:

```
import re
s="ATATAGTAGATGAATGGGATAGAAAG"
print([m.start()+1 for m in re.finditer(re.escape('TAG'), s)])
```

Will give you a list of the indices. Best to make a function:

```
def allIndex(w,s):
    return [m.start()+1 for m in re.finditer(re.escape(w), s)]
```

Comment: This is the accepted answer in the above dupe. As a 10k+ user you should close the question rather then repeat answers...